# AJAX PHP pasar valor de select a un controlador codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Tengo un problema sobre el que estoy muy confundido. Tengo un cuadro de selección dinámicamente generadas mediante una consulta en php con codeigniter:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <select onchange="func(this.value)">
    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
    <?php foreach ($array as $id=>$nombre) echo '
    <option value="',$id,'">',$id.' '.'('.$nombre.')','</option>'; ?>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="listaPersonal"></div>
```

Soy completamente nuevo para AJAX, pero necesito usar jQuery y Ajax para pasar la variable this.value a un controlador para su uso en una consulta posterior.

Aquí está mi script:
el codigo que tengo en la respuesta de ajax es el siguiente maqueto en una tabla el resultado q mando a un div en la vista html

```html
<script>
function func(selectedValue)
 {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/sis/personal/mostrar",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {option : selectedValue},
        success: function(respuesta) {
            
         var registros = eval(respuesta);
    
        html ="<table><thead>";
        html +="<tr><th>ID</th><th>apellidos</th><th>dni</th><th>telefono</th></tr>";
        html +="</thead><tbody>";
        for (var i = 0; i < registros.length; i++) {
            html +="<tr><td>"+registros[i]["id_personal"]+"</td><td>"+registros[i]["apellidos"]+"</td><td>"+registros[i]["dni"]+"</td><td>"+registros[i]["telefono"]+"</td></tr>";
        };
        html +="</tbody></table>";
        $("#listaPersonal").html(html);
          
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

esta es la consulta que tengo el modelo que recibe un parametro que es justamente el que qiero obtner del select

```html
function consulta($valor){
  $this->db->select('id_personal, apellidos, dni , telefono');
  $this->db->from('personal');
  $this->db->WHERE('personal.id_personal', $valor); 
  $consulta = $this->db->get();
  return $consulta->result();
 }
```

Comment: ¿solo quieres saber cómo obtener en el controlador los datos que envías con ajax?

Comment: efectivamente y si esa es la manera correcta de obtener el valor del select, voy adjuntar el codigo que tengo el modelo y para la respuesta de ajax

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener datos en el controlador que se han enviado mediante ajax, se accede al objeto `input` de `CI_Controller`. A través de éste objeto puedes obtener los valores enviados.

```
$this->input->post("option");
```

Tu consulta quedaría asi:

```
function consulta(){
        $selectedOption = $this->input->post("option");
        $this->db->select('id_personal, apellidos, dni , telefono');
        $this->db->from('personal');
        $this->db->where('personal.id_personal', $selectedOption); 
        $consulta = $this->db->get();
        return $consulta->result();
}
```

En la línea:

```
$selectedOption = $this->input->post("option");
```

Es donde obtenemos el valor para la llave `option` que has enviado por ajax.

Comment: Si creo que esa es la forma correcta de hacerlo en code_igniter.

Comment: agrege el codigo q  me faltava a la  pregunta y el tuyo y no realiza ninguna accion? cual podria ser el problema

Comment: ¿Qué acción esperas que haga? Esa instrucción solo obtiene el valor "option" que has enviado desde el cliente. ¿Te refieres a que la consulta no te trae resultados?

Comment: Si lo que me hacia falta era él código en él controlador y ya agrege él que compartiste, y edite la pregunta y agrege él código q tengo en la respuesta de ajax. Con todo eso no pasa nada no tengo ningún error, pero tampoco sucede nada

Comment: Por favor sé explícito. ¿Cuál es el tu problema **exactamente**? ¿No te trae los registros? ¿El valor "option" te da null?

Comment: No me trae los registros...

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta para mostrarte el proceso.

Comment: Esto quedaría en él controlador??  $selectedOption = $this->input->post("option")

Comment: Pues claro. En el controlador es donde obtienes los valores que se envían desde el cliente.

Comment: sigue sin mostrarme los datos solo se dibuja la tabla, sin los valores, el problema debe estar en el ajax

Comment: Lo que debes haber hecho desde el inicio es comprobar el valor de `$selectedOption` en orden de saber si estás recibiendo el valor deseado. Haz un simple var dump para que veas el valor.

Comment: efectivamente no me me llega nada a $selectedOption :(

Answer (score 0):

El metodo que utilizas en ajax es POST,

```
.
.

$valor = $_POST['option'];
$resultado = $this->mimodelo->consulta($valor);
```

donde option es el nombre que le estas colocando en

```
data:{option:selectedValue}
```